# %typemap and %exception for error codes from C functions for SWIG, Python

Tags: python, c, exception, swig

I've got some C code that I want to expose to Python. It has a calling convention like this:

```c
int add(int a, int b, int *err)
```

where the return value would be (a+b) or whatever, but if something went wrong, then I would get an error code in *err. I want to wrap this function so that it behaves like this, from the Python perspective:

```py
def add(a,b):
    if something_bad:
        raise RuntimeError("something bad")
    return a+b
```

This should be easy, right? But I'm not finding it so.

Here is something that I have that works, but look out for the `myerr3` kludge:

```c
%module myswig
%feature("autodoc","1");

%{
int add(int a, int b, int *err){
    if(a < 0)*err = 1;
    if(b < 0)*err = 2;
    return a+b;
}

char *err_string(int err){
    switch(err){
    case 1:return "first argument was less than 0";
    case 2:return "second argument was less than 0";
    default:return "unknown error";
    }
}
%}

%typemap(in,numinputs=0) int *err (int myerr = 0){
    $1 = &myerr;
};

%exception{
    $action
    if(myerr3 != 0){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError,err_string(myerr3));
        return NULL;
    }
};

int add(int a, int b, int *err);
```

This behaves as it should, eg with

```py
import myswig
print "add(1,1) = "
print myswig.add(1,1)
# prints '2'

print "add(1,-1) = "
print myswig.add(1,-1)
# raises an exception

# we never get here...
print "here we are"
```

but I can't really use this solution, because if I have another function like

```c
int add(int a, int b, int c, int *err)
```

then my `myerr3` kludge will break down.

What's the better way to solve this problem, without changing the calling convention of the C code?

Comment: Why is it an error to add negative numbers?

Comment: I suspect that's a trivial example of what in reality is a more complicated function showing the way it indicates success/failure

Comment: that's right. the full application is http://ascend4.org/FPROPS, which is a fluid properties library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Karl Wette, via the swig-user mailing list:

> You could modify your "in" typemap by moving the declaration of
>   "myerr" inside the typemap:
>
> ```
> %typemap(in,numinputs=0, noblock=1) int *err {
>    int myerr = 0;
>    $1 = &myerr;
> };
> ```
>
> So long as there's only one "int *err" argument in each function, this
>   should be fine. You can then use "myerr" directly without the argument
>   number.

This seems to be exactly the right solution, no kludges required. Thanks Karl!

Answer (score 3):

The trick is not to use `%exception` but to define `%typemap(argout)`.  Also don't refer to your temporary variable directly.  The `%typemap(in)` suppresses the argument in the target language and provides a local temporary variable, but you should still refer to the argument itself in `%typemap(argout)`.  Here's a modified version of your original .i file.  I've also added more generic exception throwing, so it should work for other languages also:

```
%module x
%feature("autodoc","1");

// Disable some Windows warnings on the generated code
%begin %{
#pragma warning(disable:4100 4127 4211 4706)
%}

%{
int add(int a, int b, int *err){
    if(a < 0)*err = 1;
    if(b < 0)*err = 2;
    return a+b;
}

char *err_string(int err){
    switch(err){
    case 1:return "first argument was less than 0";
    case 2:return "second argument was less than 0";
    default:return "unknown error";
    }
}
%}

%include <exception.i>

%typemap(in,numinputs=0) int *err (int myerr = 0) {
    $1 = &myerr;
}

%typemap(argout) int* err {
    if(*$1 != 0) {
        SWIG_exception(SWIG_ValueError,err_string(*$1));
    }
}

int add(int a, int b, int *err);
```

And here is the result:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import x
>>> x.add(1,1)
2
>>> x.add(3,4)
7
>>> x.add(-1,4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "x.py", line 73, in add
    return _x.add(*args)
RuntimeError: first argument was less than 0
>>> x.add(3,-1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "x.py", line 73, in add
    return _x.add(*args)
RuntimeError: second argument was less than 0
```

Comment: argout. I wish I'd thought of using it like that. So much cleaner than any of mine.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to accept that it won't be re-entrant you can use a global instead of `myerr3`, e.g.:

```
%{
static int myerr = 0;
%}

%typemap(in,numinputs=0) int *err {
    $1 = &myerr;
};

%exception{
    $action
    if(myerr != 0){
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError,err_string(myerr));
        return NULL;
    }
};
```

---

The other alternative is to slightly abuse the `freearg` typemap, instead of the `%exception`:

```
// "" makes sure we don't go inside {}, which means using alloca is sane
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) int *err "*($1=alloca(sizeof(int)))=0;"

%typemap(freearg) int *err {
    if (*$1 != 0) {
       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError,err_string($1));
       SWIG_fail;
    }
}
```

Or if you can't use `alloca`:

```
%typemap(in,numinputs=0) int *err {
    $1=malloc(sizeof(int));
    *$1=0;
}

%typemap(freearg) int *err {
    if ($1 && *$1 != 0) {
       PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError,err_string($1));
       // Don't leak even if we error
       free($1);
       $1=NULL; // Slightly ugly - we need to avoid a possible double free
       SWIG_fail;
    }
    free($1);
    $1=NULL; // even here another arg may fail
}
```

---

There's a third possible (bodge) approach you might use:

```
%{
static const int myerr1 = 0;
static const int myerr2 = 0;
static const int myerr3 = 0;
static const int myerr4 = 0;
static const int myerr5 = 0;
//...
%}

%typemap(in,numinputs=0) int *err (int myerr = 0){
    $1 = &myerr;
}

%exception{
    $action
    // Trick: The local myerrN from the typemap "masks" the const global one!
    if(myerr1 != 0 || myerr2 != 0 || myerr3 != 0 || myerr4 != 0 || myerr5 != 0) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError,err_string(myerr1|myerr2|myerr3|myerr4|myerr5));
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

The trick is that the specific `myerrN` from the typemap masks the `static const` global ones - the if statement is always referring only to one, local constant which is the only one that can be non-zero

Comment: I was hoping to be able to make it reentrant... also I can't get this approach to work at all with methods on a C object, http://www.swig.org/Doc1.1/HTML/SWIG.html#n5

Comment: Hmm I can't think of a cleaner solution than making it `__thread`. Can you give an example of one that doesn't work with all objects? And wouldn't it be simpler just to `throw` and handle that rather than using a pointer?

Comment: @jdpipe - I think I worked out a better(?) way of doing this - it's reentrant and uses `freearg` instead

Comment: mmm... that looks like a solution, but it's not as tidy as I'd hoped. Maybe __thread is better? Let's say I *could* change the calling convention for the library... is there a neater solution then, eg with a function like `err = add(int a, int b, int *res);`

Comment: @jdpipe - I realised there's another way that it can be solved - you can make the if statement check all the positions, but have all except the one you're using always be 0. It's a bit of a bodge, but it fits within the language rules and SWIG ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions... another solution from Karl Wette below seems to be the best approach, using the 'noblock' trick to allow a local variable to be 'kept'.

Comment: `%exception` is really for wrapping code that throws exceptions.  See my answer for a solution that uses an `argout` typemap for generic handling of `int* err` arguments.