# SWIG Technique to Wrap Unsigned Binary Data

Tags: swig

I have a C function that returns a unsigned char* that represents binary data. I noticed in the documentation that SWIG has a nice typemap to handle binary data as input to a C function, but what about when a C function returns binary data and its unsigned?  Any ideas?

**swig.i:**

```
%apply (char *STRING, size_t LENGTH) { (const char data[], size_t len) }
%inline %{
void binaryChar1(const char data[], size_t len) {
  printf("len: %d data: ", len);
  for (size_t i=0; i<len; ++i)
    printf("%x ", data[i]);
  printf("\n");
}
%}
```

**java:**

```
byte[] data = "hi\0jk".getBytes();
example.binaryChar1(data);
```

**C Example:**

```
 enw_resultrow_t *result_row = getResultRow();
 unsigned char *blob;
 while ((blob = getBinaryFromRow(result_row, &length))) {
            char fname[32];
            FILE *fp;
            i++;
            snprintf (fname, sizeof(fname), "FileXYZ", i);
            printf ("Blob from %d:%s is saved in %s has %d bytes\n", i, 
                    aSender?inet_ntoa(aSender->sin_addr):"???", fname, length);
            if ((fp = fopen (fname, "w"))) {
                l = fwrite (blob, sizeof (unsigned char), length, fp);
                printf("Successfully wrote %d bytes to file\n", l);
                fclose (fp);
            } else {
                printf("Error writing file");
            }
        }
```

Comment: So you want to return a known size array from C to Java? How do you communicate the size if you return the pointer? A second "output" from the function, e.g. via a pointer `unsigned char *getData(size_t *out_length); // stores size of returned data in out_length`?

Comment: @awoodland - I added more context to the question as I was being too generic.  I added a C example of how the getBinaryFromRow is being used from C.  From Java I would like to mimic the C example and call the getBinaryFromRow.  I do know the length as its in the length output param. The while loop keeps reading until there isn't anymore binary data.  The length param is the number of bytes for each loop iteration.  I don't need to write a file on the Java side, but its a good test if the api/wrapping worked.  I'm fine with a byte[] or whatever structure is easiest in SWIG.

Comment: what's the declaration of `getBinaryFromRow()` which I assume is the example you care about

Comment: @awoodland - unsigned char * getBinaryFromRow(struct result_row_t *row, int32_t *length) that is the function I'm trying to wrap.

Comment: I'm working on an answer for this with/without the bounty. I need some time to write it up though :)

Comment: @awoodland - sounds good, just figured it was bounty worthy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created a test case that mirrors what you're trying to do (I think):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

enum thing {
  ONE=1,
  TWO=2, 
  THREE=3
};

static signed char *get_data(enum thing t, size_t *len) {
  *len = (size_t)t;
  signed char *ret = malloc(sizeof(signed char) * (*len));
  for (size_t i = 0; i < *len; ++i) {
    ret[i] = i;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

To wrap `get_data()` I used the following interface:

```
%module test

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%typemap(jni) signed char *get_data "jbyteArray"
%typemap(jtype) signed char *get_data "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) signed char *get_data "byte[]"
%typemap(javaout) signed char *get_data {
  return $jnicall;
}

%typemap(in,numinputs=0,noblock=1) size_t *len { 
  size_t length=0;
  $1 = &length;
}

%typemap(out) signed char *get_data {
  $result = JCALL1(NewByteArray, jenv, length);
  JCALL4(SetByteArrayRegion, jenv, $result, 0, length, $1);
}

%include "test.h"
```

Basically what this does is set the return type from the `get_data` function to be a Java array right from the JNI code all the way through the SWIG proxy. Once that's done it sets up a temporary `size_t` called `length` which will be used to make the call to the real C function and store the result. (I'd not seen `noblock` before I saw [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9469495/168175), it tells SWIG not to make the typemap argument independent and as such means there can only ever be one `size_t *len` parameter to a given function, take a look at what it does to the generated wrapper code if you're curious).

Once that's set then all that remains is to allocate an array using a JNI call and copy some values into it.

I tested this with:

```
public class run {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
    byte[] test1 = test.get_data(thing.ONE);
    System.out.println(test1.length);
    System.out.println(test1 + ": " + test1[0]);

    byte[] test2 = test.get_data(thing.TWO);
    System.out.println(test2.length);
    System.out.println(test2 + ": " + test2[0] + ", " + test2[1]);

    byte[] test3 = test.get_data(thing.THREE);
    System.out.println(test3.length);
    System.out.println(test3 + ": " + test3[0] + ", " + test3[1] + ", " + test3[2]);

  }
}
```

Which then gave:

```
1
[B@525483cd: 0
2
[B@2a9931f5: 0, 1
3
[B@2f9ee1ac: 0, 1, 2
```

I cheated slightly by making mine be a `signed char`. If you want to make it unsigned you either need to use a cast (beware the loss of sign at best) or `short`/`int` with an appropriate conversion.

Be careful with memory ownership in your real code.

Comment: @c12 - did this work for you or do you want me to elaborate on it?

Comment: I'm still trying to apply it to the unsigned C function.  I will have some follow up questions for you but I'm trying to figure them out before asking.

Comment: you briefly mentioned memory ownership at the bottom, for this example would you use %newobject and %typemap(newfree) char * "free($1);"; here?

Comment: @c12, I think that would work, I'm not 100% sure what the ownership semantics of the JNI functions themselves are though and it depends on the function you're wrapping too. You#ll want to be more specific than just `char *` though too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to implement a mechanism of your own.
swig provides a module named 'cdata.i'.
You should include this in the interface definition file.

Once you include this, it gives two functions cdata() and memmove(). Given a void * and the length of the binary data, cdata() converts it into a string type of the target language. memmove() is the reverse. given a string type, it will copy the contents of the string(including embedded null bytes) into the C void* type.

Handling binary data becomes much simple with this module.
I hope this is what you need.